# Automatic Running Timer

Tags: swift, timer, label

I am trying make a very simple countdown timer that is displayed on the screen without having to press a start button; continous. However, when I run the simulator only "Label" shows up on the screen with no countdown. I have my outlets correctly hooked up and am throwing no errors, and even following guides I can't figure what I am doing wrong. Any simple solutions?

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!


var seconds = 15
var timer = Timer()


func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector(("updateTimer")),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {
    seconds -= 1
    timerLabel.text = String(seconds)
}






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    runTimer()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

}

Comment: Is that your real, unmodified, copy/pasted code? It should abort with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppName.ViewController updateTimer]: unrecognized selector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `selector` syntax in this line first :

```
func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

and add `@objc` to this func :

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
    seconds -= 1
    timerLabel.text = String(seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just start timer at:

```
func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.runTimer()
}
```

and stop it at:

```
func viewDidDisappear() {
      super.viewDidDisappear()
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
}
```